# How to find out numbers of children element by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I want to find out number of children`<textarea>`into one`<td>`by jquery. i try to use jquery each method but i can't.

Comment: `$(any selector).length` will give you number of matched elements.

Comment: it's not working, i want to know number of element e.g. : 10 Textarea etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$('td > textarea').length;
```

It will give all `textareas` that fall under any `td`, if you want to specific `td` you can have id for `td` & do

```
$('#tdid > textarea').length;
```

Comment: it gives TypeError : Number is not a function.

Comment: show your code in a  fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/53u6rq09/